# Solving differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = ay - by^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

this is my second differential equation I have to solve and I need some help:

> $$\frac{dy}{dx} = ay - by^2 ; a > 0, b \ge 0$$

Okay, so this is what I have done:

$dy/dx - ay = -by^2 | :y^2$

$\frac{1}{y^2}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{a}{y} = -b$

Substitution: $u = \frac{1}{y}$, so $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{-1}{y^2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$ and therefore $ - \frac{-du}{dx} = \frac{1}{y^2} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$

Insert this above:

$- \frac{du}{dx} - au = -b$

$\frac{du}{dx} + au = b$.

I hope this is correct. If so, I do not know how to conclude.

Thank you very much for any kind of help!

Comment: Correct. Now make integrating factor!

Comment: Another way could be $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac 1 {ay-by^2}$ then partial fraction, integration to get $x(y)$ and so on.

Comment: MyGlasses
Thank you - I haven't learned yet what "making integrating factor" is. How can I get the correct integrating factor?

@ClaudeLeibovici I tried so, having $\frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{a-by}$ and then getting $A=\frac{1}{a}$ and $B=\frac{b}{a}$. This leads, by integration, to $\frac{1}{a}ln(y) - \frac{b}{a} ln (a-by)$. What now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We write

$$\frac{\mathrm d y}{a y - b y^2} = \mathrm d x$$

Using partial fraction expansion,

$$\left( \frac{1}{y} - \frac{b}{b y - a} \right) \mathrm d y = a \, \mathrm d x$$

Integrating both sides, we obtain

$$\ln \left( \frac{y}{b y - a} \right) = a x + c$$

where $c \in \mathbb R$ is an integration constant. Hence,

$$\frac{y}{b y - a} = \gamma \, \exp (a x)$$

where $\gamma := \exp (c)$.

Comment: Okay, I see that I made a mistake when integrating $\frac{b}{by-a}$. Thank you!

Comment: My solution does not agree with Wolfram Alpha. I probably made a mistake, too. I cannot find it, though.

Answer (score 2):

For the first order equation $u'+au=b$ the function
$$I(x)=e^{\int a dx}$$
is integrating factor, here $I=e^{ax}$. Multiply two sides of equation in $I$ then
$$e^{ax}u'+e^{ax}au=be^{ax}$$
with this factor, left side is exact so
$$(e^{ax}u)'=be^{ax}$$
then
$$u=e^{-ax}\int be^{ax}dx+Ce^{-ax}$$

Comment: This is general case, here equation $u'+au=b$ solve simply with $\dfrac{du}{b-au}=dx$!